# Class template having pointers arguments with default value

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to understand the below code snippet

```
template <typename T>
class testopaque {
public:
    void test(T var = T()) {}
};
```

How does the default argument work when called with a pointer type example int *

```
int main() {
    testopaque<int *> obj1;
    obj1.test();
}
```

what would the compiler generate when obj1.test() is called. I get a compiler error when I try

```
int main() {
    int * var = int *();
}

error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
int * ptr = int *();
```

Comment: It's more like `using T = int*; T var = T();` which does compile - live - https://godbolt.org/z/vYzoxza89

Comment: Long story short, a default-initalised pointer is a zero-initialised pointer. It is initialiased to a null pointer.

Answer (score 10):

Suppose you have `x=1+2`.  Would you expect `x*3`, which is 9, to equal `1+2*3`, which is 7?

A similar problem is happening here.  `int*()` isn't the same as `T=int*` then `T()`.

Try `(int*){}`, which solves the combined parsing and precident problems.  Or `using T=int*; int* x=T();`, or even `int*x={};`

(Simply using `(int*)()` doesn't solve the problem due to how types are parsed, which is probably something you don't want to go too deeply into if you value your sanity.)

Answer (score 8):

This is an example of how C++'s complicated syntax and grammar just produces unexpected results:

```
int *();
```

Your C++ compiler is very tempted to interpret this construct as a "function returning a pointer to an `int`". Your C++ compiler gives in to this temptation, with the observed results.

You need to teach your C++ compiler what you're trying to accomplish here:

```
typedef int *intp;

int main()
{
    int * var = intp();
}
```

Comment: It's like someone came along and said "you know how some languages have Turing-complete parsers? Could we do *that* but make it more confusing somehow?" And thus C++ was born.

Comment: Surely it would be clearer to write `intp var = intp();`?

Answer (score 6):

When you use an expression like:

```
T var = T();
```

Where `T` is a pointer type then `var` will be assigned `nullptr`